# Can't see the object in rendered image after motion tracking

Tags: camera, tracking

[image]

[image]

[image]

I was watching camera tracking tutorials in youtube (Blender 2.8 Camera tracking tutorial (part 1)) and did exactly as shown in the video, but after motion tracking in the composite tab I can't see the suzanne object in the rendered view , after pressing the f12 I can only see the suzanne object but not the background, even though I can see everything in the "set up tracking scene in 3d view".

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the render layer has no alpha channel.

Enable Film> Transparent.

[image]

[image]