# Camera tracking : Rendered image only render 3D objects and doesnt render the video image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I am new to Blender(2.9) ,I followed several Camera Tracking tutorials. But when I render my final image, it only renders the 3D objects and the video image doesn't get rendered.If I change the "Fac" value of the "Alpha Over" node, it blends the images but does not give the result I want . (all the tutorials keep this "Fac" value to 1.000)

Following shows my View Layers,Collections (I deleted the 'BackGround' layer generated by the Camera Tracker)

[image]

This shows the Compositor settings:

[image]

This is my rendered output:
[image]

Any tips on how to fix this ?

Comment: found the answer here : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186151/cant-see-the-object-in-rendered-image-after-motion-tracking

Comment: yes. thank you .

Comment: How about upvoting the answer if that did solve your issue?